# JQuery get attribute from HTML element var

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have the following Jquery code:

```
 $(function () {
     $("div[id$='xxx']").click(function ()
     {
         $('.greenBorder').each(function (i, obj)
         {

         });
     });
 });
```

When a DIV called `xxx` is clicked, each HTML `img` with a class of `greenBorder` is iterated through. I would like to access the `src` attribute of each `img`. I can't figure out how to pull this value out. The `obj` function parameter contains the HTML element object, but how do I get the value out of that object? If this were C/Java/C#, I would cast it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the jQuery [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function, you can access the current element with `this`. You can then jQuery select the element using `$(this)`, and read the attribute with `$(this).attr("src")`.

**Example:**

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id$='xxx']").click(function ()
    {
        $('.greenBorder').each(function (i, obj)
        {
            console.log($(this).attr("src"));
        });
    });
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `obj` in place of `this`. You could also read the `src` attribute with `this.src` or `obj.src`.

Comment: Would `this.src`, `obj.src` and `$(obj).attr('src')` work too?

Comment: @user3558931: Yes they would, I added a note of this to the answer.

Comment: Although not part of my question, how I could I get attribute values for the *next* element in the DOM?

Comment: I'll give you the check momentarily.

Comment: Scrap that, answered my own question with `$(this).next().attr('value')`

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you. I also tried `this.src`, `obj.src` and `$(obj).attr('src')` and I can confirm all work perfectly. Thank you.